# Bad Request 400 with Spring

Tags: json, spring-mvc

I get an HTTP Bad Request when trying to reach my REST API. The issue is that Spring does not give much information to debug.

The URL is `http://localhost:8080/webapp/network/v1/jobs.json?callback=jQuery203040624934318475425_1377165238418&sEcho=1&iColumns=1&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10&mDataProp_0=id&sSearch=&bRegex=false&sSearch_0=&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&iSortingCols=1&bSortable_0=true&_=1377165238419`

The controller:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/network/v1/jobs")
public class JobsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<JQueryDatatablesPage<Job>> list(
            @RequestParam int iDisplayStart, @RequestParam int iDisplayLength,
            @RequestParam int sEcho, @RequestParam String search) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In my pom file, I have jackson:

```
    <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

The json extension is used to return JSONP:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>jsonpCallbackFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jsonpCallbackFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The debugger stopped in the filter but I still get a Bad Request, and the debugger does not stop in the `list` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake parameter `search` was not in the URL. Just added `@RequestParam(required = false) String search)`